# My code is taking a really long time to run however my program is telling me otherwise

Tags: java, avl-tree

So I'm currently trying to test how long it takes for an AVLTree to be populated with different amounts of data. When adding small amounts of data to the tree like 16 objects or 2824 objects, my program is able to run within seconds (I'm using my phone stopwatch to record the time). When I add ~11000 objects to the tree however, it takes around 28 seconds and when I try to add 250000 objects to the tree my program seems to never finish running.

Within the program, I have added a variable that stores the current time at the beginning of the code and another variable that also stores the current time at the end so that I can roughly calculate how long it took the program to run. What is interesting though is that when I populated the AVLTree with 2824 objects it says it took ~1.56 seconds to run and when I populated the AVLTree with ~11000 objects it apparently took the same time to run.

Using my stopwatch to see that it took ~28 seconds to run compared to the ~1.56 seconds my program is telling me it took makes it really hard to see what is really causing the problem. The compiler I'm currently using is Eclipse Java Oxygen by the way.

```
public class AVLTreeTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        AVLTree<IPAddress, URL> avlTree = new AVLTree<IPAddress, URL>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/data/top- 
                250k.txt"));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split("\t");
        IPAddress newIP = new IPAddress(values[1]);
        URL newURL = new URL(values[0]);

        avlTree.add(newIP, newURL);
        }

    }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    avlTree = null;
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double time = stop - start / 1000;
    System.out.println("Took: " + time + " second(s)");
    }
}
```

Comment: `double time = stop - start / 1000;` with this you will only get a nonsense value for the time. Should be `(stop - start) / 1000.0`. Also, the times are all too high. Something seems to be wrong with the AVL Treee implementation.

Comment: Do you invoke Garbage Collector explicitly anywhere within this process ?

Comment: A lot of the time is in the try/catch and initializing the file i/o.  These are non-dependent(no matter how many records are read) overheads.  As far as the stopwatch vs measured time, You have included compilation and execution setup time. As stated above, the computation given will round to the nearest second, but that in itself does not the discrepancy.  Try running it from the command line and measure the difference.